# Invalid Argument in IE8 using R2D3.js when appending 'tr' tag

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js, internet-explorer-8, invalid-argument

I have an application that uses D3.js, but I have to make it compatible with IE8... So I used R2D3.js, which seems to be a really good alternative for SVG manipulation. But for basic tags...

I use it to manage data inside a table, but when it comes to append a new row, IE says:

> Line: 8450 / Error: Invalid argument.

I have looked around, but I found no clue.

Here is a simple example of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="r2d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script><![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
        <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
        </table>

        <script>
var dataset = [
    {
        name: 'Foo',
        age: 42
    },  
    {
        name: 'Bar',
        age: 21
    }
];

var table = d3.select('table');
table.selectAll('tr').data(dataset)
    .enter().append('tr')
    .selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) {
            return [d.name, d.age];
        })
        .enter().append('td')
            .text(function(d) {return d});
        </script>
    </body>
<html>
```

This works perfectly with Firefox, but crashes on IE8.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw9c5b0r/1/).

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at R2D3 source code, its using an the addEventListener method which is only supported starting from IE9:

https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=addeventlistener

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

```
R2D3Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener) { 
    this.domNode.childNodes[i].r2d3.addEventListener(type, listener); 
}
```

This explains why it crashes on IE8

Comment: I haven't analyzed the code carefully, but I'm pretty sure it's using a custom function to polyfill addEventListener.  The whole point of R2D3 is that it polyfilles IE7/8 support.

Comment: Ok. But how does it work with SVG element? Should not it crashes like for basic element?